# Meta-property of a graph in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases, tinkerpop

While traversing a Neo4j graph, I want to set some key-val pair against every property of the graph. It is easy to do using meta-properties, but in Neo4j graph feature, "Meta-property" feature is false(not there).Is there any other way possible to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

As Neo4j does not support that feature natively in their graph database, meta-properties can only be simulated as part of the neo4j-graph implementation. They are disabled by default and therefore you must explicitly turn them on as part of your configuration when constructing the graph using the `gremlin.neo4j.metaProperties` option:

```
gremlin> conf = new BaseConfiguration()
==>org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration@6c99bc97
gremlin> conf.setProperty('gremlin.neo4j.directory','/tmp/neo4j')
gremlin> conf.setProperty('gremlin.neo4j.metaProperties',true)
gremlin> graph = Neo4jGraph.open(conf)
==>neo4jgraph[community single [/tmp/neo4j]]
```

You can read more about this [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_multi_meta_properties)

Comment: mallete how do we set this property when using the neo4j-java-driver? By default the meta properties and variable features are set as false and hence we aren't able to use these features. Can you please let us know?

Comment: hmmm...i'm not sure what would work in that situation. i think you should ask the developers of that library directly if anything can be done.